# AdminFaces - Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2.2, maven

Bom dia,

Estou iniciando com o `Admin-Faces`. Ao incluir a dependência ao projeto (eclipse), estou recebendo o erro abaixo:

> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for org.omnifaces:omnifaces:jar:2.1

No `pom.xml` coloquei a seguinte dependência:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.adminfaces/admin-template -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-template</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC18</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No seu projeto, clica com o botão direito do mouse, selecione ***Maven*** e escolha a opção ***Update Project***

Comment: Edjane. É exatamente quando faço o update que a biblioteca (jar) não é encontrada.

Comment: Você colocou a biblioteca do Ominifaces?

Comment: Edjane. Coloquei sim.  Obrigado pela força. Consegui uma solução de contorno: baixei o JAR e o adicionei manualmente ao repositório local. Ainda não descobri o motivo de não achar no repositório central.